# Ways of Updating my Ubuntu 10.10 Notebook

Tags: 10.10

I have recently bought a second-hand notebook, which is running Ubuntu 10.10. I am completely new to Ubuntu and bought this machine because I want to get away from Windows. I now realise that 10.10 is no longer supported and I was advised that I needed to download and install Ubuntu 13. I tried to do this, but was required to give a password in order to do so. I do not have the password, as this is a second-hand machine.

I know that I could start from scratch and install 13, but I'm reluctant to do this, owing to my lack of familiarity with Ubuntu and limited technical skills. Is the only way forward for me to do a complete installation of v13, is there a way to bypass the password?

Thanks in anticipation,

Dave

Comment: Your best option is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu.  This will be a great way for you to become more familiar with Ubuntu.  Get the updates you need during installation and sit back and enjoy the freedom that comes with Linux.  You have broken your chains from Windows....congratulations!

Comment: As this machine came with 10.04 It may not run 13.04 well depending on the hardware specification of your PC. You may want to take a look at [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) which is aimed at the lowest specification machines. Or take a look at [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) which requires a more powerful PC than Lubuntu but will run on lower spec machines than Ubuntu. And finally take a look at [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) Which requires a reasonably modern PC. You can create CD/DVD of each of these or a [bootable-USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-